# Soldering Iron WEP70 struggling with thermal reliefs

Tags: soldering

After my good ol' €35,- soldering iron died after 10 years of loyal service I treated myself to a Weller. Those things are so expensive that I ended up with the low budget version. And that is a [WEP70 (70W) soldering iron with a WE1010](https://www.weller-tools.com/professional/EUR/en/T0053298699) (85W) station.

Like the title says, the iron is struggling with every ground pad that has a thermal relief. I have normal thermal reliefs. I can apply solder and it flows to the pad somewhat but than it cools down and it simply does not melt well again.

Even 1206 resistors on ground pads are a pain.

I tried temperatures between 340C and 380C. It does not seem to make a difference.

Why does this iron disappoint me this much? Is this common? Or is there something wrong?

Comment: What kind of tip shape/size are you using?

Comment: I've got a similar (although older) Weller soldering station and ground pads aren't giving me too much trouble. Have you tried removing the soldering tip, inspecting everything, and then screwing it back on? There might be debris between the tip and the heating element.

Comment: What alloy solder and flux are you using? And what is your board resting on?

Comment: I use basic solder with flux. 63% Sn, 2% flux. Resin core. 0.8.mm wire

Comment: The tip is the default one. it is a little flat on the end. I will order me some new tips. It seems to have spots where solder does not want to go.

Comment: If using a single-sided board, get an inexpensive electric cooking griddle and dedicate it to electronics work.  Careful of plastic parts.  Adjust the griddle to about 110C / 250F.  Set the board on it, give it a few minutes to heat up, then solder your tough joints - they will be much easier with the added heat.  Then set the board on a wire rack to cool.  Can do non-relieved pads this way, along with solder-paste and surface-mount (higher griddle temp) with some practice.  Also try a lower melting-point solder.

Comment: Get shorter, fatter tips with a chisel tip, or turn the heat up even a little higher.   Put a small amount of solder on the tip so you have a 'blob' when you're pre-heating the pad, not just tip-to-PCB which touches at a single (small) point.   This increases the cross sectional area, thus reducing thermal resistance.  The temp sensor for the soldering iron isn't in the tip, so it can't really know what the temp is at the tip.   BTW, I do these all the time with that iron, it's definitely very possible.

Comment: I have that iron. The entry level weller stuff largely exists to make you regret not paying for the expensive gear, but with a chisel tip it's fine for doing 1206 parts.

Comment: Ok tnx. I will get me some chisel tips.

Comment: Yeah if you are using the tip on the picture, it isn't good for much. Chisel/square shaped tips when you need heat, much finer tips when you need to do fine pitch SMD jobs. Also, Weller is mid-range quality... if you had just tossed in another 50€ you could get the "budget" model of a premium brand instead.

Comment: which brand would you recommend? A colleague was very positive about JBC irons. He was particular happy about that he could switch tips during usage without the need of extra tools. They have some kind of quick release system.

Comment: @bask185 I would recommend Metcal. Never used JBC but in general it would seem that Metcal and JBC are regarded as the premium brands. Weller and Hakko are half-decent.